# If $C$ is a closed subset of a metric space, then $\bar{B}(C, r)$ is a closed subset also?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $C$ be a closed subset of $X$. Let $\bar{B}(C, r) :=\{x\in X \ | \ \exists c \in C \ \textit{s.t.} \  d(x, c)≤r \}$. Then is $\bar{B}(C, r)$ a closed subset also?

Is the statement true if $X$ is a normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $C$ is a closed, bounded convex subset of $X$?

Comment: Let $C=\{y_1,y_2,...\}$ be such that the distance between any two of its elements if $1$. Let $x_1,x_2,...$ be such that $d(x_i,y_j)=2$, for all $i,j$, $d(x_i,x_j)=1$ for $i\neq j$. Let $x_0$ be such that $d(x_0,x_i)=1+1/i$, $d(x_0,y_i)=2+1/i$.

Comment: No - simple counterexample in the answer below. It's true if you assume $C$  is _compact_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oberve the space $X=\mathbb R-\{0\}$ equipped with subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb R$.

Then $C:=(0,\infty)$ is a closed subset.

But $\overline B(C,1)=(-1,\infty)\setminus\{0\}$ is not closed.